# AFTER MySql restart : #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

AFTER MySql restart i get the this error when I try to update or insert a row : #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.

The strange thing is that when I remove and add the key constraint again with phpMyAdmin the problem is gone. Also this I only have this problem with MAMP, not with WAMP, and also not on any other server until now.
I use MySQL 5.5.9 , can anyone give a solution for this ?
Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Do the keys concerned include string-type columns?  This could be character-set related.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with MAMP :/
I don't know about the cause but "FLUSH TABLE" solved it.

Comment: FLUSH TABLE seems to solve indeed the problem, I will see in the future if the problem repeats itself. Thanks for the advise.