# Unable to insert row after MySQL server restart (Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails)

Tags: mysql

I have a simple DB with two tables (Games, Screen) one related to another through a foreign key (a Game can have many Screens, a Screen 'belongs to' one Game).
When I try to insert a new row in the Screen table everything works as expected. I'm using this query to add a new Game:

```
INSERT INTO Game ( title ) VALUES ( "Game 1" );
```

And this one to add new Screens:

```
INSERT INTO Screen ( title, game_id ) VALUES ( "screen 3", 1 );
```

I can insert as many rows as I want with this query with no problem. However, if I just restart the MySQL server (I'm using MAMP, http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) and execute the same query again, I get this error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`screen`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Screen_Game` FOREIGN KEY (`Game_id`) REFERENCES `Game` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

I have no clue about what the problem can be, since this only happens after server restart.
From the error message it looks as if the Game table didn't have a row with id = 1, but it does...

Here's the script I use to create the database:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `mydb` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Game`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Game` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Game` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Screen`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Screen` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Screen` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Game_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `Game_id`),
  INDEX `fk_Screen_Game_idx` (`Game_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Screen_Game`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Game_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Game` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Maybe I haven't set my table relationship right?

Also, this thread seems very similar to mine: [AFTER MySql restart : #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363611/after-mysql-restart-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-co) but I tried executing

```
FLUSH TABLES;
```

with no luck...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Drop your db and recreate it.

Comment: Is there a `Game` with `id` 1?

Comment: Option NO ACTION for foreign key is not good. You might delete data from Game, But Game_id data in Screen is still there. 
Try to make request SELECT * from Screen WHERE Screen.Game_id NOT IN (SELECT Game.id FROM Game). If request will return some values, the data integrity in your DB is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Mihai: Yes, dropping the db solves it, but I guess I shouldn't need to do that. Right now my DB is mostly empty (just testing stuff), but in the future it will contain data that I don't want to loose...

Gim: yes, there's a Game with that id.

Nick Tsarev: Will take note of that, thanks. However I can't test your query anymore, please read below:

SOLVED

Finally I found this post:

[Weird ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796834/weird-error-1452-23000-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constr)

which solved the problem. Looks like my local MySQL version had a bug causing the problem. I just upgraded to 5.5.25 and looks like it works correctly now.

Thanks a lot everyone.